# flutter image_cropper crash

Tags: android, flutter

I tried crop image with this plugin and worked great on iOS but on Android, app will crash.
Console says like those.

> V/BoostFramework(22266): mAcquireFunc method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
>   V/BoostFramework(22266): mReleaseFunc method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
>   V/BoostFramework(22266): mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
>   V/BoostFramework(22266): mIOPStart method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
>   V/BoostFramework(22266): mIOPStop method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
>   V/BoostFramework(22266): BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@544293f W/art     (22266): Before Android
>   4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable D/BitmapLoadUtils(22266):
>   maxBitmapSize: 2078 D/BitmapWorkerTask(22266): Uri scheme: file
>   E/TransformImageView(22266): onFailure: setImageUri
>   E/TransformImageView(22266): java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission
>   denied E/TransformImageView(22266):   at
>   android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:283)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:200)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:981)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:839)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:793)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   com.yalantis.ucrop.task.BitmapLoadTask.doInBackground(BitmapLoadTask.java:100)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   com.yalantis.ucrop.task.BitmapLoadTask.doInBackground(BitmapLoadTask.java:44)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   E/TransformImageView(22266):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266): Process: com.example.droidemo, PID: 22266
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure
>   delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=69, result=96,
>   data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.example.droidemo/com.example.droidemo.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4211)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4254)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1584)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6242)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method) E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266): Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:293)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMethodCodec.encodeErrorEnvelope(StandardMethodCodec.java:70)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.error(MethodChannel.java:208)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperDelegate.finishWithError(ImageCropperDelegate.java:99)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperDelegate.onActivityResult(ImageCropperDelegate.java:82)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   io.flutter.app.FlutterPluginRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterPluginRegistry.java:210)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   io.flutter.app.FlutterActivityDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityDelegate.java:139)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:138)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7009)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4207)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22266):  ... 9 more Lost connection to device. Exited
>   (sigterm)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Android Platform, we are required config `UCropActivity` into `AndroidManifest.xml` below application. IOS is not required to do that.

Read detail on: https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper

```xml
<activity             
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"             
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"             
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hnvn/flutter_image_cropper/issues/78#issuecomment-536887525

i have solved it as replace

```
if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
}
if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
    && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
}
if (requested.group == "androidx") {
    if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
        details.useVersion "${targetSdk}.+"
    }
```